# Two transcendental elements and their shifting

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, transcendental-numbers

This is not a homework assignment or  question from an exam  but it comes to my mind but I was not able to figure it out. Let $\{u,v\}$ be algebraically independent subset of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q.$

Put $z:=q v+p$ for some nonzero $p,q\in\mathbb Q$. Clearly, $\{z\}$ is algebraically independent set. My question is how about $$\{u,z\}$$  Is it algebraically independent set as well? Please if you know show me how it prove it or disprove it.

Thank so much in advance.

Comment: GEdgar, I edited Thank you

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I said for nonzero $p,q\in Q$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\{z\}$ is algebrically independent only if $q\ne 0$.
In that case, $\{u,z\}$ is also algebraically independent:
Suppose $f(u,z)=0$ with $f\in\Bbb Q[X,Y]$. Then $g(u,v)=0$ with $g(X,Y)=f(X,qY+p)$, hence $g(X,Y)\equiv 0$. But $f(X,Y)=g(X,\frac{Y-p}q)$ (where we make use of $q\ne 0$).

Comment: Is it true for general case, I meant, Let $A$ and $B$ be algebraically independent sets and $A\cap B=\emptyset$.Put,  $ C:=\{q b+p \colon \ b\in B\ \&\ p,q\in\mathbb Q\setminus\{0\}\}.$ Then $A\cup C$ is algebraically independent sets. Is true as well.